# How to get int from string that has 2 ints separated by char?

Tags: java, string, int

Scanner.next() return a string that contains a string "10,5".

How could I get these 2 int values into 2 different int variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution using Java 8:

```
String data = "10,5";
int[] numbers = Arrays.asList(data.split(",")).stream()
                      .map(String::trim)
                      .mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).toArray();
```